# how to change array format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a array

```
Array (
    [Hindi] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Examinations] => 124
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Assignment] => 124
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Projects] => 124
                )

        )

    [Punjabi] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Examinations] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Projects] => 124
                )

        )

)
```

And so on . but i need following format as per my requirement .Does anybody have idea how to make an array like this

```
 Array (
        [Hindi] => Array
            (
                [Examinations] =>124
                 [Assignment] => 124
                 [Projects] => 124
               )

            )
```

and so on

Anybody have idea how to do this

Thanks

Comment: Iterate over the current array (and maybe it's sub-arrays, though `array_merge` might just work well) and build the new one...

Comment: How to do this i am new to php no idea

Comment: Then read some documentation first: About [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: If you are new to PHP you should read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) before asking this kind of questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: i don't think so array merge will work here

Comment: Where is the array coming from? Might just be easier to edit the manner in which it's constructed.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you need:

```
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {

    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
      $new_array[$key][key($v)] = current($v);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to convert the original array into the resulting array format? Try this. Assuming your original array is called `$languages`:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($languages as $lang => $scores) {
    foreach($scores as $score) {
        foreach($score as $category => $number) {
            if (!is_array($result[$lang]) {
                $result[$lang] = array();
            }
            array_push($result[$lang], array($category => $number))
        }
    }
}
```

`$result` is your new array.

But if you are trying to create the resulting array format, but are ending up with the former one, you'll need to provide here the source code you are using to generate the former one, so we can help you change it so that it generates the correct format.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution:

```
<?
$array = array (
        'Hindi' => array(
                array(
                        'Examinations' => 124
                ),

                array(
                        'Assignment' => 124
                ),

                array(
                        'Projects' => 124
                )

        ),

        'Punjabi' => array(
                array(
                        'Examinations' => 0
                ),

                array(
                        'Projects' => 124
                )

        )

);

$resultingArray = array();

$currentArray = $resultingArray;
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $arrayPart = array();
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $innerArray){
            $arrayPart = array_merge($arrayPart, $innerArray);
        }
    }
    $resultingArray[$key] = $arrayPart;
}

?>
```

Comment: I haven't! I just translated your var_dump into PHP array. Run this code and you will see that it does what you need.